# How to reconcile Babel plugins with Jest and Webpack in my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babel-jest

I am using Jest (my preferred testing framework) for testing .jsx files in a frontend React project.

This command was used to install Jest: **npm i --dev jest babel-jest @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react react-test-renderer**

These are the installed dependencies from the package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
```

In order to run the project which relies on Webpack, the .babelrc file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
      "react",
      "env",
      "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

However, I need to change the presets to the following so that Jest will work with test cases.

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

If I run the project with the above presets, I receive this message on the localhost server:

> Error: Child compilation failed:   Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):   Error: Requires Babel
> "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a
> compatible ver  sion of @babel/core, it is likely that something in
> your build process is loading the wrong version. Insp  ect the stack
> trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention
> "@babel/core" or "babe  l-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While
> processing preset: "C:\GIT\TypeORMcar\frontbackTypeORMcar
> \frontend\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js")